# vue-chartjs not updating on array.push()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vue-chartjs

I'm using vue-chartjs to show a line chart on my website. When I click on a button it's supposed to add another value to the chart. The dataset is updated but the chart is not.

**LinieChart.vue**

```
<script>
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  },
  methods: {

  }
}
</script>
```

I added this to my **dashboard.vue**
Where the chart is displayed

```
<line-chart
          ref="LineChart"
          :chart-data="chartdata"
          :options="options"
          class="h-64"
        />
```

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'auth',
  layout: 'dashboard',

  name: 'Dashboard',

  components: {
    temporaryDisableModal,
    LineChart
  },

  data: () => ({
    sensors: [],
    sensorTypes: [],
    valueTypes: [],
    measurements: [],
    websockets: [],
    lastMeasurements: null,
    loaded: false,
    chartdata: null,
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true
    }
  }),
  beforeMount () {
  },
  async mounted () {
    this.fillData()
    const self = this
    // self.fillData()
    await self.getSensors()
    self.loaded = false
    self.loaded = true
    console.log('Sensors:')
    console.log(self.sensors)
    console.log(self.sensors.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < self.sensors.length; i++) {
      console.log(i)
      console.log('Subscribed to ' + self.sensors[i].id)
      self.measurements[self.sensors[i].id] = []
      console.log(self.measurements)
      window.Echo.channel('measurement.' + self.sensors[i].id).listen('.App\\Events\\WebsocketMeasurements', (e) => {
        console.log('Data:')
        console.log(e)
        self.websockets.push(e.measurement)
        self.measurements[self.sensors[i].id].push(e.measurement)
        console.log(self.measurements)
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    log () {
      this.chartdata.labels.push(10)
      this.chartdata.datasets[0].data.push(10)
      this.chartdata.datasets[1].data.push(10)
    },
    fillData () {
      this.chartdata = {
        labels: this.getRandomInt(),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'value_1',
            borderColor: 'rgba(131, 24, 48, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(131, 24, 48, 0.3)',
            data: this.getRandomInt()
          },
          {
            label: 'value_2',
            borderColor: 'rgba(216, 42, 81, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(216, 42, 81, 0.3)',
            data: this.getRandomInt()
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    getRandomInt () {
      let array = []
      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (6) * Math.random() * 3 * Math.random() * 9) + 15)
      }
      console.log(array)
      return array
    },
 // other functions...
</script>
```

So when I execute the function `log()` it should add the value `10` as label and a dot in the line. It is added to the dataset, just not to the chart.

When I executed the `log()` function i get an error when hovering the chart:
`Chart.js?30ef:6719 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined`
This does not happen when I haven't executed the function yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with vuecharts, instead of modifying nested elements on data reassign them all along, so instead of this:

```js
      this.chartdata.labels.push(10)
      this.chartdata.datasets[0].data.push(10)
      this.chartdata.datasets[1].data.push(10)
```

Do this:

```js
this.chartdata.labels = MyNewArrayOfLabels
this.chartdata.datasets= [  //Me new array of datasets
   {
    label: 'value_1',
    borderColor: 'rgba(131, 24, 48, 1)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(131, 24, 48, 0.3)',
    data: this.getRandomInt()
   },
   {
     label: 'value_2',
     borderColor: 'rgba(216, 42, 81, 1)',
     backgroundColor: 'rgba(216, 42, 81, 0.3)',
     data: this.getRandomInt()
   }
 ]
```